# Expected number of pieces of a chessboard

Tags: probability, combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

If n squares are randomly removed from a $p \ \cdot \ q$ chessboard, what will be the expected number of pieces the chessboard is divided into?

Can anybody please provide how can I approach the problem? There are numerous cases and when I go through case consideration it becomes extremely complex.

Comment: That's immensely difficult. There's no general answer.  What is your motivation here?

Comment: I cannot find a suitable approach to the problem. That's why I am asking for just a hint not the fully worked solution itself.

Comment: You can't get the exact answer without getting a computer to check every case.  It might be possible to say something useful, but I'd need to know why you're trying to solve this particular problem and what sort of answer you need.

Answer (score 2):

I am posting this as an answer to make it more visible. This is currently a Brilliant.org problem, in which the specific case $ 2 \times 500 $ is asked for. While it is an interesting problem meriting discussion, that should wait until after 8:00 PM EST 5/19 when the problem set is closed.

Answer (score -1):

2 =         = 2 piece
3 = (3+1)/2 = 2 piece
4 =         = 2 piece
5 = (5+1)/2 = 3 piece
6           = 3 piece
7 = (7+1)/2 = 4 piece
8 =         = 4 piece

Series = (n+1)/2 pieces

Regards,
Yuvaraj

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Is this supposed to be an answer to the question? It helps to format answers using MathJax (see FAQ) Just some friendly advice. Regards